How to use space indent in template toolkit
I am working in template tool kit. I am writing a tt2 programming but if I use space indent it is reflecting in output as well. Is there any way to dont refect in output
       [% FOREACH md IN data.keys.sort -%]
       [% FOREACH timeplate IN data.$md.keys.sort -%]
       [% IF (timeplate == 'timeplate') -%]
       [% FOREACH tp IN data.$md.$timeplate.keys.sort -%]
       [% FOREACH proc IN data.$md.$timeplate.$tp.procedure -%]
       [% procedure.$proc = tp -%]
       [% END -%]
       [% END -%]
       [% END -%]
       [% END -%]
       [% END -%]


The default delimiters in Template Toolkit are [% and %]. The alternative versions with a hyphen [%- and -%] "eat" whitespace up to the first newline character. Try this code:
use Template;

my $tt = Template->new;

my $input = <<'EOF';
top
[%- IF 1 -%]
    text
[%- END -%]
bottom
EOF

$tt->process(\$input);

The output is one line:
top textbottom

Experiment with the different delimiters and also try to insert empty lines in order to understand the effect.
If you absolutely have to remove whitespace before or after literal text you can use a trick and either assign it to a variable and output that variable or turn it into a string literal:
use Template;

my $tt = Template->new;

my $input = <<'EOF';
[%- variable = 'bar' -%]
       [%- 'foo' -%]
       [%- variable -%]
EOF

$tt->process(\$input);

The output is the string "foobar" without any newlines.
The sad truth is that Template Toolkit's whitespace processing capabilities are very limited. It would be really helpful to have not just the delimiter versions with the hyphen but others like [%= or [%|, with different behaviour, but that cannot be implemented without breaking strict compatibility with existing versions.
BTW, you are using -%] in your own code, probably without noticing it.
